# HTML canvas lines are drawn gittery

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have problems with the HTML canvas. When I move the line rapidly, it get's drawn in a gittery fashion, and I can see multiple lines. I don't know if this is a problem with the framerate and my eyes, or that I'm doing something wrong... Here is my code:

```js
const can = document.getElementById('can');
const ctx = can.getContext('2d');

can.width = innerWidth;
can.height = innerHeight;

function triangle(x1, y1, x2, y2){
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    ctx.lineWidth = "2";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2 + (y1 - y2));
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#33cc33";
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x2, y2 + (y1 - y2));
    ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.stroke();
}

addEventListener('mousemove', (e)=>{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
    triangle(can.width / 2, can.height / 2, e.clientX, e.clientY);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="can"></canvas>
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: If the question is already answered somewhere else, I'm sencerely sorry, I searched for a bit and couldn't find it...

Comment: What is `loop`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I altered the code a bit and forgot to remove that, edited the post

Comment: What you are describing sounds like [persistence of vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision). If that's the case, the solution would be to draw blurred between the two drawings, but I'm not sure it's worth the pain. Just to be sure, on which browser are you experiencing this issue?

Comment: That could very well be, and I don't know if there IS a solution to this problem as it only occurs when you move the line at quite a rapid pace.

Comment: Older LCDs have slow switching speeds (Time to orient crystals between  on / off states) Average modern LCDs have about a 5ms switching speed and thus there is about 1/3rd of a frame where the previous pixel state persists. This can be mitigated by reducing the amount of change between frames (eg make the line brighter / darker when rapid movement is detected))